# Help understand output of dnsmasq logs and find performance issues by reading dnsmasq log

Tags: linux, dns, dnsmasq

I have `dnsmasq` installed on server and it is heavily used. I have the following `dnsmasq` log in the `/var/log/syslog` when given the signal "SIGUSR1":

```
Jul 16 13:45:50 server1 dnsmasq[427008]: time 1531748750
Jul 16 13:45:50 server1 dnsmasq[427008]: cache size 10000, 18355/597070 cache insertions re-used unexpired cache entries.
Jul 16 13:45:50 server1 dnsmasq[427008]: queries forwarded 1510313, queries answered locally 15347110
Jul 16 13:45:50 server1 dnsmasq[427008]: queries for authoritative zones 0
Jul 16 13:45:50 server1 dnsmasq[427008]: server 100.1.2.3#53: queries sent 242802, retried or failed 0
Jul 16 13:45:50 server1 dnsmasq[427008]: server 100.2.3.4#53: queries sent 1371704, retried or failed 0
```

I have set cache size to 10000 which is max allowed value. The application which uses `dnsmasq` for requests also feels slow.

How do I understand the `dnsmasq` log and know if these logs represent performance issues due to low cache size?

Comment: Related - https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-speed-up-dns-caching-on-your-linux-machines-with-dnsmasq/ & http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/dnsmasq-man.html. Also you could benchmark it - http://xmodulo.com/how-to-test-dns-server-speed-on-linux.html.